# PowerShell script to delete folder in Users on AD computers

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've been trying to create a script that removes a folder in C:\Users in an administrator's name from all AD computers that was initially created from a PDQ deployment. When I attempt to run it, I get an error about a missing file path. Search results yielded a long script, though my current script is only a couple lines in length. I want it to be as lightweight as possible so performance isn't heavily degraded. Am I missing something? Code below.

$Destination = 'C:\Users\foldername'

Get-ChildItem $Destination | ForEach-Object {remove-Item -Force -recurse}

Comment: That only references the local computer. How are you planning on executing this on remote computers? Also, the second line can just be `Remove-Item $Destination -Force -Recurse`.

Comment: It'll be in a separate isolated PDQ deployment file, executed to remote PCs after a bit of testing locally

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the Group Policy features that can do this for you?

Comment: I don't have the necessary permissions to add it as a GPO, otherwise I'd go that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like could work assuming you have privileges, but running Get-ADComputer with a wildcard filter could take a long time depending on how many there are

```
$allComputers = Get-ADComputer -filter "Name -like `"*`"" | Select Name
$Destination = "C:\Users\folder"
Foreach($computer in $allComputers.Name)
{
    Invoke-Command -computername $computer -ScriptBlock {
        param($Destination)
        if(Test-Path ($Destination)){
            Write-Host "Removing $Destination from $computer"
            Remove-Item $Destination -Force -Recurse
        }
    } -ArgumentList $Destination
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this modifiable to test locally? I imagine by editing the wildcard to  include a single computer's name instead?

Comment: Yes or simply do $allComputers = @("server01","server02","etc") as an array, then in the foreach you would just have $allComputers, not $allComputers.Name